# File not found in Node.js

Tags: node.js

I'm having trouble understanding how to access a local file in a Node.js Expresss Webapp.

I want to use the [excel-parser](https://npmjs.org/package/excel-parser) package to read a file I have placed in /public/assets/ this should be read on load of the index page.

So I have started by creating an ExpressJS app, and creating the following in my index.js:

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
  var excelParser = require('excel-parser')

  res.render('index', { title: 'Excel test' });

  excelParser.worksheets({
    inFile: '/assets/test_data.xlsx'
    }, function(err, worksheets){
      if(err) console.error(err);

      console.log('[INFO] Worksheet output: ');
      console.log(worksheets);
    });
};
```

In ny console though I receive the error 'File not found', and '*worksheets*' is undefined.

I have also tried with the following paths:

- /public/assets...
- __dirname + '/public/assets/...'
- __dirname + '/assets/...'

All offer the same error.

Comment: Checked file permissions?

Comment: according to docs `__dirname` isn't actually a global but rather local to each module. So it depends where your index file is.
You could `require('path')` and then `path.join(__dirname, 'public/assets')` thats when index file is in same directory as public

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to get file relatively to you app root directory. As right now '/assest' will try to get it from root of your drive.

You can get root directory of main JS file early in module:

```
var path = require('path');
var root = path.dirname(require.main.filename);
```

And then use it:

```
inFile: root + '/public/assets/test_data.xlsx'
```

Comment: Thanks that led me to the solution. I also used [fs.exists](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_exists_path_callback) to help me track down that I was calling a file that actually existed.