# Nodejs & express can't find public folder

Tags: node.js, express

My node.js app can't find the public folder. I've tried using connect static and express static from this answer: [static files with express.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434001/static-files-with-express-js) and also this answer: [File not found in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17575492/file-not-found-in-node-js)

But I still can't get it working. I get the content of the page I try to display, but not any of the links to css and js files.

Any ideas?
This is my app.js file.

```
var express = require('express'),
post = require('./routes/posts'),
web = require('./routes/web'),
http = require('http'),
stylus = require('stylus'),
nib = require('nib'),
path = require('path');

var app = express();

function compile(str, path) {
    return stylus(str).set('filename', path).use(nib());
}

app.configure(function () {

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.multipart());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(stylus.middleware({src: __dirname + '/public', compile: compile}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.bodyParser({ keepExtensions: true, uploadDir: __dirname + '/upload/photos' }));
});

//app.use(app.router);

//Web
app.get('/',        web.frontPage); 

app.post('/posts',           post.findAllPosts);
app.post('/posts/:id',       post.findPostById);
app.post('/postAdd',          post.addPost);
app.put('/posts/:id',       post.updatePost);
app.delete('/posts/:id',    post.deletePost); 

app.get('*', function(req, res){
    res.render('404');
});

http.createServer(app).listen(80);
console.log('Listening on port 80...');
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is caused by this:

```
app.get('*', function(req, res){
  res.render('404');
});
```

Because you're declaring the `app.router` middleware (which handles that catch-all route) *before* the static middleware, the router gets all the requests for static files too, and if they aren't handled by any of your other routes, it will generate a 404.

The solution would be to move the static middleware to before the router. The same also needs to be applied to the Stylus middleware and the `bodyParser` middleware, to make sure they are called *before* your routes:

```
app.use(stylus.middleware({src: __dirname + '/public', compile: compile}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.bodyParser({ keepExtensions: true, uploadDir: __dirname + '/upload/photos' }));
app.use(app.router);
```

(although it seems that you can skip the `bodyParser` middleware, since you're using the `json`, `urlencoded` and `multipart` middlewares already; the `bodyParser` middleware is just a very thin wrapper around those three)

Comment: thanks worked straight away. but if I remove the bodyParser how do I specify the upload folder?

Comment: @just_user pass your options to the `multipart` middleware instead :)